# Laravel 7 : Make failed validation response 200 instead of 422

Tags: laravel, api, response, laravel-7

I'm creating a Laravel 7 application.

I have created a POST API that accepts 2 parameters and added validation on them. When validator fails, it gives response "422 unprocessable entity" and gives an error in JSON format like this :

```
{
    "message": "The given data was invalid.",
    "errors": {
        "mobile_no": [
            "The mobile no must be 10 digits."
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I want the same response with error code 200 instead of 422.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide the code of the API controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an error handler for this purpose. 
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/errors#render-method

```
 public function render($request, Exception $exception)
 {
     if ($condition)) {
       return response()->json($content, 200);
     }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Check inside function exception you need and replace it with successful response

Answer (score 1):

For laravel 8, i override method invalidJson in app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
protected function invalidJson($request, ValidationException $exception)
{
    return response()->json([
        'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
        'errors' => $exception->errors(),
    ], 200); //parent method return 422
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the `Laravel` documentation, section [**Manually Creating Validators**](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#manually-creating-validators):

```
<?php
 
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
 
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
 
class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Store a new blog post.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
            'body' => 'required',
        ]);
 
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            // here add your 200 response
            return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
 
        // Retrieve the validated input...
        $validated = $validator->validated();
 
        // Retrieve a portion of the validated input...
        $validated = $validator->safe()->only(['name', 'email']);
        $validated = $validator->safe()->except(['name', 'email']);
 
        // Store the blog post...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here in Laravel 9 you can do this in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`:

```
$this->renderable(function (ValidationException  $e, $request) {
    if ($request->is('api/3.0/*')) {
        return response()->json([
            'codigo' => 406,
            'mensaje' => $e->validator->errors()->any()
                ? $e->validator->errors()->first()
                : 'Credenciales incorrectos',
            'errores' => $e->errors()
        ], 406);
    }
});
```

The snippet above sets a `406` status code for all routes starting with `api/3.0/*`.